# Audio Reactive LED using Logic Gates

Tags: led, logic-gates, sound

I have a project regarding the application of logic gates. I decided to build a sound reactive LED's.but before that here's my first diagram,
[image]
As you can see, there's no TIP31C on that diagram. the question is, is it possible to insert that TIP31c on this diagram to make my sound reactive led work? because I based the sound reactive led from this circuit diagram.[image]
Can I place that TIP31C on my first diagram just to make my desired output which is to have an audio/sound reactive LED's? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why is there an LDR for this "audio reactive " LED system?

Comment: You're connecting multiple LEDs to a single CD4k output? Good luck.

Comment: This question makes no sense I vote to close

Answer (score 1):

I'm gong to assume that you know virtually nothing about electronics, and need to learn.

Your first circuit simply won't work, or at least won't work well, as you would know if you had ever built it. It is obviously intended to provide a blinking LED(s) if the anbient light level gets below a certain level as determined by the VR1. However, it does this in part by changing the power supply to the IC, and this will have bad effects near the trigger point. Worse, the setup ensures that the IC will never get the full 5 volts, and neither will the LEDs. Finally, even given whatever voltage the IC gets, it is completely incapable of driving much current through the LEDs, so they won't get very bright. And even when they do, they won't be of uniform brightness. Connecting LEDs in parallel is a very bad idea.

As for trying to drive the IC with audio, that really isn't going to work. At 5 volts power supply, a CD4093 requires about 3 volts input, and either line or headphone circuits won't do that. For instance [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TAC-vVxSok0) shows a bit over 1 volt max for an iPhone output.

Now, on to your beloved TIP31. I suspect that you may have tried it. If you did, you're lucky you didn't destroy your LEDs. If driven hard enough, it will attempt to put the full 12 volts across 4 LEDs in series. There are two possibilities. If you have white LEDs, with more than 3 volts per LED required for full brightness, they simply will never turn on very well. If you're using something like red, green or yellow, which typically take about 2 volts, the 12 volt battery will drive far more current through them than they can take in the long run. Since you're using (apparently) a headphone jack to provide your audio, you might get away with it for a while, since the LEDs will only be on for brief pulses, and the audio source can't drive all that much current into the transistor base.

So, stop trying to use a TIP31 to drive a reactive LED. Start by actually building the first circuit. Once you do that you can add your TIP31 to the output, and you can destroy the LEDs.